# Adding phenomena across reference frames

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I've found some confusion of relativity in my thoughts about magnetism and it's relationship with special relativity. Consider the simple wire and its magnetic effects on a charge: without a current the simple wire is just comprised of  an equal density of positive and negative charges, but with a current, the negative charges (electrons) begin to flow.  As they move their space is compressed, and their relative density increases with respect to the positive charges, which are stationary in our frame.  So then if there is another stationary charge in our frame, positive or negative, just outside the wire, we should expect the increased density of negative charges should have an electric effect on it.  But since $F_B = qv\times B$, a stationary charge should *not* experience a force.  My explanation for this is that in our frame, the electrons are moving and their relative density increases, which causes a force, but in the electrons' frame, it is the *positive* charges that appear to be moving equally in the opposite direction, so, since they are the opposite charge, their relative density increases equally and produces an equal and opposite force. "Adding" these forces together across the frames results in equilibrium---which is what we'd expect.  This "adding" seems to work explaining the magnetic force experienced when the external charge is moving as well if we also consider its frame as well ours and the electrons'.

Is that reasonable? Can you simply "add" the phenomena that occur across the various frames?